# webAI-user.bat Python error message after installing TensorRT

Tags: tensorrt, stable-diffusion

I am running Stable Diffusion Automatic1111 on an Nvidia card with 12 GB of VRAM.  I just completed the installation of TensorRT Extension. However, every time I launch webAI-user.bat I get the error message that begins: "The procedure entry point ?destroyTensorDescriptorEx..."  This message pops up just when webAI_user.bat gets to "Launching Web Ui with arguments: --xformers --nohalf vae --medvram-sdxl --no-half".  (Please see attached JPG.) I can't tell if TensorRT is actually speeding things up or not; I haven't used it much yet.  But even if it does work, I would like to get rid of the popup error message.  I have to click multiple times to get it to close.  Any help will be greatly appreciated, but sorry, I don't know Python.
Zaffer

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found that by following these directions on the github Nvidia page, I got rid of the popup error.  The directions were actually posted in response to a different "not found" problem, but they worked to solve mine.  Here's the link.
Zaffer

https://github.com/NVIDIA/Stable-Diffusion-WebUI-TensorRT/issues/27#issuecomment-1767570566